# Starting a new intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to start a new activity in my class.  I cant call

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Do I need to extend Activity for that??  If so, how?

resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`startActivity()` is a method on `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), so you can call it on any object that is of a class that inherits from `Context`. Frequently, we call `startActivity()` on an existing `Activity`.

For example, here we have an `Activity` that calls `startActivity()` on itself to start up another activity:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.exint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ExplicitIntentsDemoActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void showOther(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class));
  }
}
```

The `showOther()` method is invoked if the user clicks on the `Button` defined in `res/layout/main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:onClick="showOther"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Activities/Explicit))

Comment: How do I make the class inherit Context?

Comment: Do NOT ever extend `Context`. Pass one through a constructor or a method parameter. The point was that `Activity` extends `Context`.

Comment: @Bobdabiulder: "How do I make the class inherit Context?" -- you don't. You already have a `Context`, such as your `Activity`. Call `startActivity()` on it. I have edited the answer to include a sample of calling `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

One of these two approaches should work. If you are starting an activity from another activity all you need to do is something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where thisActivity is the current activity and nextActivity is a new activity you want to launch.

If you don't have a context, for instance in the case that you have created your own class that doesn't extend Activity, then you can still get the context by making it a parameter of the constructor.

For instance, in the example below the constructor gets a reference to the Context

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> films;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> o) {
    mContext = c;
    mFilms = o;
}
```

Then you can start a new activity from this class

```
public void startNewActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This constructor should be used in another class, perhaps an activity, that already has a reference to the context:

```
new ImageAdapter(this, output);
```